# Whats is the best way to load language JSON file in golang?

Tags: go

I have json files for language support and each json files around 3 mb but i wondered which way is good for performance, lightweight and fast in golang.

reading from json files `fmt.Printf("%s: %d\n", lang["tr"].Back)`

or

putting all json into a map and read from map

`{"tr": { "Back": "geri", "Next": "ileri", "Day": "gün"}}`

10 years ago when we worked with old language we had montly 20-30 gb traffic only for reading xml language files. thank you

Comment: You shouldn't be approaching this as "How do I load JSON" but rather as "What is our localization solution?" Answer that, and the rest will fall into place. There are a few libraries for go that do this. Do a Google search, speak to your translators, and determine what's best for your business needs.

Comment: thank you for your message i will do a search for more information